# Partcopy not working under Windows 10 (x64)

Tags: bootloader

Partcopy failed to write to my HDD image while copying FAT32 bootloader.
Any suggestions? I tried to copy it to J:, but it did nothing.

Comment: What does this have to do with nasm?

Comment: The NASM compiled it OK, but when I started porting it into a hard drive, it does nothing. Bah humbug.

Comment: If you have a programming question, please show the code that you are having problems with and describe the specific problem and what you have done to debug it. Reduce the program to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, I used this: partcopy boot.bin 0 200 -h2 200.